# -ERR wrong number of arguments for get command - Redis server error

Tags: python, linux, bash, redis, redash

I am trying to install redash version 10.0.0 without docker. There is a script for that in the redash forum (https://discuss.redash.io/t/bring-back-bootstrap-sh/2436/12) and this is for redash 5.0, but  I had modified that for Redash 10. (I have upgraded some requirements also to fit in Python 3.8.). Also I need to install on Ubuntu 20.04.

The problem is when I execute the script, it executes successfully, but all services are up and running except the redash server.

When I type on web `localhost:6379` (for the redis server) I get this error:

> -ERR wrong number of arguments for 'get' command

I have tried with redis 3.5 and 5.0 versions.